# How to extract value from json object in C#

Tags: json

Below are code snippet is my json object which i want bind the data with my model. And
I want to extract only transaction_details values in to my sample model as list.

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "msg": "3 out of 3 Transactions Fetched Successfully",
  "transaction_details": {
    "446094091884bf8534e6": {
      "mihpayid": "00000000003",
      "request_id": "",
      "bank_ref_num": "1154234544",
      "amt": "1.00",
      "transaction_amount": "1.00",
      "txnid": "446094091884bf8534e6",
      "additional_charges": "0.00",
      "productinfo": "Buy Bitcoin",
      "firstname": "Pramod",
      "bankcode": "ICIB",
      "udf1": "",
      "udf3": "",
      "udf4": "",
      "udf5": "",
      "field9": "Successful Transaction",
      "error_code": "E000",
      "card_type": null,
      "error_Message": "NO ERROR",
      "net_amount_debit": 1,
      "disc": "0.00",
      "mode": "NB",
      "PG_TYPE": "ICICI",
      "card_no": "",
      "udf2": "",
      "addedon": "2017-02-24 12:14:03",
      "status": "success",
      "unmappedstatus": "captured",
      "Merchant_UTR": "dfksdfld",
      "Settled_At": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    "446094091884bf8534e7": {
      "mihpayid": "00000000002",
      "request_id": "",
      "bank_ref_num": "1154392922",
      "amt": "1.00",
      "transaction_amount": "1.00",
      "txnid": "446094091884bf8534e7",
      "additional_charges": "0.00",
      "productinfo": "Buy Bitcoin",
      "firstname": "Pramod",
      "bankcode": "ICIB",
      "udf1": "",
      "udf3": "",
      "udf4": "",
      "udf5": "",
      "field9": "Successful Transaction",
      "error_code": "E000",
      "card_type": null,
      "error_Message": "NO ERROR",
      "net_amount_debit": 1,
      "disc": "0.00",
      "mode": "NB",
      "PG_TYPE": "ICICI",
      "card_no": "",
      "udf2": "",
      "addedon": "2017-02-24 16:38:00",
      "status": "success",
      "unmappedstatus": "captured",
      "Merchant_UTR": "fasdfafasdfsd",
      "Settled_At": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    "446094091884bf8534e8": {
      "mihpayid": "00000000001",
      "request_id": null,
      "bank_ref_num": null,
      "amt": "1.00",
      "transaction_amount": "1.00",
      "txnid": "446094091884bf8534e8",
      "additional_charges": "0.00",
      "productinfo": "Buy Bitcoin",
      "firstname": "Pramod",
      "bankcode": "ICIB",
      "udf1": "",
      "udf3": "",
      "udf4": "",
      "udf5": "",
      "field9": "User interrupted by pressing back button",
      "error_code": "E1206",
      "card_type": null,
      "error_Message": "Transaction interrupted by pressing back button",
      "net_amount_debit": "0.00",
      "disc": "0.00",
      "mode": "NB",
      "PG_TYPE": "ICICI",
      "card_no": "",
      "udf2": "",
      "addedon": "2017-02-27 14:03:00",
      "status": "failure",
      "unmappedstatus": "userCancelled",
      "Merchant_UTR": null,
      "Settled_At": null
    }
  }
}
```

**This my Sample Model**

```
public class sample
{
    public string mihpayid { get; set; }
    public string request_id { get; set; }
    public string bank_ref_num { get; set; }
    public string amt { get; set; }
    public string transaction_amount { get; set; }
    public string txnid { get; set; }
    public string additional_charges { get; set; }
    public string productinfo { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string bankcode { get; set; }
    public string udf1 { get; set; }
    public string udf3 { get; set; }
    public string udf4 { get; set; }
    public string udf5 { get; set; }
    public string field9 { get; set; }
    public string error_code { get; set; }
    public string card_type { get; set; }
    public string error_Message { get; set; }
    public string net_amount_debit { get; set; }
    public string disc { get; set; }
    public string mode { get; set; }
    public string PG_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string card_no { get; set; }
    public string udf2 { get; set; }
    public string addedon { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string unmappedstatus { get; set; }
    public string Merchant_UTR { get; set; }
    public string Settled_At { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you jusrt need to send to controller using post method

Comment: i want to extract the real value from json object.

Comment: where you want to extract in controller or in jquery ? if in controller please chk my answer

Comment: no i am looking plain c# file

Comment: Update in answer for C# please check

Answer (score 0):

```
  for c# 
  var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var objsample  = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<sample>(jsonInput)

   // for mvc 

     $.ajax({
        url: '/submit',
        data: JSON.stringify(yourdatastring),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });

   **Controller**

    [HttpPost]
    public void Submit ([FormBody] Sample sample)
    {
    }
```